# Why does WhatsApp Web need a click from me for updating?

Tags: whatsapp

Sometimes, roughly every 2-3 months, WhatsApp Web (web.whatsapp.com), that I access through Chrome or Chromium, displays a green banner at the top of the left column:

[image: Update available - Click to update Whatsapp]

<sup>"*Update available. Click to update WhatsApp*"</sup>

Clicking triggers a page refresh, then WhatsApp operates normally (it doesn't require a new pairing with the device). Actually, it is operative while the banner is displayed too, i.e. before accepting the update, too.

This usually appears at the start of a session (right when I visit the page), but it has also happened mid-session.

I'm confused by this request: the page has already the permission to set (and, I believe, update) its cookies, and it doesn't run any additional software on my computer. I wouldn't think it needs to do anything client side. **So *what* is it updating and *why* would it need my click?**

Comment: Old question but still relevant and unanswered? I would love to understand this as well. I assume it needs reloading because it wants to update scripts and needs to refresh, but doesn't want to refresh by itself without user consent?

Comment: i haven't seen it happening in a while now, so I don't know if it's still relevant. As per your conjecture: I think I've seen the message appearing just at the start of a session, so when it could have just loaded with the new scripts

Comment: Funnily enough, it JUST happened, in a long-running session. So yes, it's still relevant.

Comment: Just happened to me today, with a new session.

Comment: Posting as a comment since I don’t have sufficient rep for an answer. 

Part 1/2

The WhatsApp web app is fully cached in your browser & uses a [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API#Service_worker_concepts_and_usage) to manage itself. Advantages of caching an app include and are not limited to reduced payload sizes & offline capabilities. So every refresh only downloads a small payload including the service worker since the application is already cached! Pretty neat huh?

Comment: Part 2/2
A service worker [can detect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/onupdatefound) when the app is outdated and can trigger a message like the one you've mentioned. The reason not to automatically refresh is a UX decision I believe, because it would suck if the page decided to refresh itself while you were typing a message.

Comment: Thanks! That's a useful answer! How come you can't post an answer? The https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts priviledge comes at 1 rep, much earlier than the https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: I cant post an answer specifically to this question since it has been marked as a [highly active question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions)

Comment: Awad Maharoof > "The reason not to automatically refresh is a UX decision I believe, because it would suck if the page decided to refresh itself while you were typing a message" ;
But most of the time the message appears upon opening the page! I just don't understand why it wouldn't just trigger the action automatically, on a "page load" type of event.

Comment: On the question being off-topic: although my question is about a decision made by the app developers – for which we may never know the full reason – I believe it could get a valuable question nonetheless. Note my two closing questions (in bold in the post): the *what* (whcih can be inspected) and the *why would it need to* (which talks about software engineering practices in general).

Answer (score 4):

WhatsApp uses a service worker that cache some scripts, but the browser see the necessary scripts update only loaded the the page, because, he search for code change in the service worker. For this, WhatsApp hint you about it. It could also reload the page after the service worker update, but it also want that the user view the update and decides when it's opportune to reload the page.